# is it possible to loop through the ids to findViewById android

Tags: java, android, xml, findviewbyid

I Have a table created on the GUI but I'm stuck on looping through the IDs of the views as it is not a string that goes in the path. HELP anyone please!

for example IDs are tMon9, tMon10, tMon11 etc...

```
    String classgroup = "CO.DNET3";
    int semester = 2;

    Timetable t = null;
    try {
        t = new Timetable(classgroup, semester);


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    if(t!=null)
    {
        TextView tv;
        for (int i = 9; i < 18; i++) {
            if (t.getModule("wednesday", i + ":00") != null) {


                tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id. (LOOP HERE)    ); // I want to loop through ids

                String s = "";
                s+= t.getModule("wednesday", i + ":00") + "\n";
                s+= t.getRoomNumber("wednesday", i + ":00") + "\n";
                tv.setText(s);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getIdentifier` to get id of View using String name:

```
int textViewID = getResources().getIdentifier("tMon"+i, "id", getPackageName());
tv=(TextView)findViewById(textViewID);
```